# Sort 2D array according

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to sort the following 2D array according the field year?

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
(
    [from] => 44.91
    [to] => 53.56
    [next] => 108.88
    [year] => 2011

), 
[1] => Array
(
    [from] => 44.44
    [next] => 53.16
    [year] => 2010

), 
[2] => Array
(
    [from] => 42.83
    [next] => 51.36
    [year] => 2012
)
);
```

So the desired result will be:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
(
    [from] => 44.44
    [next] => 53.16
    [year] => 2010

), 
[0] => Array
(
    [from] => 44.91
    [to] => 53.56
    [next] => 108.88
    [year] => 2011

),
[2] => Array
(
    [from] => 42.83
    [next] => 51.36
    [year] => 2012
)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`uasort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)?

```
function cmp_year($a, $b) {
    if($a['year'] == $b['year']) return 0;
    return ($a['year'] < $b['year']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($your_array, 'cmp_year');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/array_multisort).

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  $years[$k] = $v['year'];
}

array_multisort($years, SORT_DESC, $arr);
```

Comment: how to do the same thing for nested array and the value to sort is inside that nested array this is not working